# An exercise question in the probability theory class

Tags: probability, random-variables, lagrange-multiplier, variance, uniform-distribution

I was asked a "simple" question by one of my students in the tutorial class, but I found myself struggling with this for about 2 hours already. Here is the question:

Assume there are $K$ constants: $0\leq C_{1}<C_{2}<...<C_{K-1}<C_{K}\leq1$; Let $X$ be a random variable with $Pr(X=C_{k})=\frac{1}{K}$, $k=1,...,K$. Find when the maximum of $Var(X)$ is attained, determine the value of $K$ and the value of $(C_{1},...,C_{K})$ when this happens.

Here are some of my ideas:

$E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^{K}C_{k}\frac{1}{K}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K}C_{k}$

$E[X^2]=\sum_{k=1}^{K}(C_{k})^2\frac{1}{K}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K}(C_{k})^2$

$Var(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=\frac{1}{K^2}\big(K\sum_{k=1}^{K}(C_{k})^2-(\sum_{k=1}^{K}C_{k})^2\big)\\~~~~~~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{K^2}\big((K-1)\sum_{k=1}^{K}(C_{k})^2-2\sum_{i\neq j}C_{i}C_{j}\big)$.

I am really wondering if it is possible to apply Lagrange multiplier method to this.

Any help and advice will be sincerely appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: For a second I thought you were after minimum; $Vax(X)$ is a convex function and therefore it will naturally have a global minimum where the derivative is zero but it will not have a maximum on any open set. You can encounter a maximum on the boundary of compact sets but you don't have a compact set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I believe I got what you want to convey. Indeed, a minimum is always attainable, just as you said.

Comment: The minimum is _not_ attainable; you can make the variance as near to 0 as you like by putting all the $C$ close together, but if they all have to be distinct then it can't ever be exactly 0. (If you allow the $C$ to be equal then the minimum is attainable, but so is the maximum.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first of all allow some of the $C$s to be equal.

The derivative of the variance w.r.t. $C_i$ is $\frac2K(C_i-m)$ where $m$ is the expectation of $X$ = the mean of the $C$s. Therefore, pushing any $C_i$ *away* from $m$ increases the variance, so a maximum-variance configuration has all the $C$ equal to either 0 or 1.

If it has $p$ 0s and $q$ 1s then the variance is $\frac{pq}{(p+q)^2}$ which, for fixed $p+q=K$, is biggest when $p,q$ are as close as possible.

So the biggest variance you can get is when "half" of the $C$s are 0 and "half" are 1. (If $K$ is odd, one of those groups will be 1 larger than the other.)

This maximum isn't attained, if you keep the restriction that all the $C$ have to be unequal. But you can get as close to it as you like by pushing "half" the values very close to (one another and to) 0 and the rest very close to (one another and to) 1.

(You didn't ask about this, but the *minimum* happens when all the $C$ are equal; this too isn't attained if you require them to be distinct but you can get as close as you like by making all the values very close together.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer in details. I believe your answer is right.

Answer (score 2):

This gives some formality to Gareth's answer (reaching the same conclusion).

**Claim:** If $X$ is any random variable that satisifes $0\leq X\leq 1$ surely, then
$$Var(X)\leq 1/4$$
and this is achieved by $X \sim Bernoulli(1/2)$.

**Proof:** Suppose $0\leq X \leq 1$ surely. Note that
$$ \left(0\leq X \leq 1\right) \implies 0\leq E[X] \leq 1$$
$$\left(X^2\leq X\right) \implies E[X^2]\leq E[X]$$
Define $m=E[X]$, so $m \in [0,1]$.
Thus
\begin{align}
Var(X) &= E[X^2] - m^2\\
&\leq E[X] - m^2 \\
&=m-m^2\\
&\leq \sup_{v\in [0,1]}\{v-v^2\}\\
&=1/4
\end{align}
$\Box$

Under the structure of your question, we can use $K=2$ and $C_1=0, C_2=1$ to achieve the max variance of $1/4$.

I'm not sure if your question also asks what to do if $K$ is fixed and cannot be chosen (so we cannot choose $K=2$). For any **even integer** $K$, we can approach the max variance $1/4$ arbitrarily closely by using $C_1=0$, $C_K=1$, and placing half the remaining $C_i$ values near $0$ and the other half near 1 (spacing them out by some small $\epsilon$ to ensure they are distinct). This is what is similar to Gareth's answer. The case when $K$ is odd is different.